# Transaction unconfirmed long time help me please

Tags: transactions, blockchain

I made a payment at 2:13 PM but this payment is still not accepted. It's about the following link >>> https://blockchain.info/en/address/359cnHYeEJoRQDVU2BnKfXp6o9uCSX89tR

SEND
June 13 @ 02:13 PM
To:
359cnHYeEJoRQDVU2BnKfXp6o9uCSX89tR
From:
My Bitcoin wallet

Is there anybody who can help me to make this payment confirmed?

I apologize for the many types of mistakes.

Thanks in advance,

Sincerely

Michel

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a fast confirmation, just wait, it has sufficient fee to get confirmed by itself.

Otherwise you have to spend one of the outputs and add enough fee to cover both transactions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,
Then I'll wait a minute. Sincerely Michel

Comment: I can't tell you how long it will take, but [here](https://jochen-hoenicke.de/queue/#24h) is a nice visualization of the mempool. Your tx is in the upper gray band. You can watch when the miners start taking tx's out of this band.